# Do you want to continue(y/n) issue

Tags: c

Do you want to continue (y/n) doesn't work in this c code. I want it to ask to enter a string when I type 'y' and exit from the program if I type n. I have tried many options, but to no avail. 
Thanks for your help

```
    do
    {
        i = 0, final = 0, s = 0;
        printf("\n\nEnter Input String.. ");
        scanf("%s", string);

        while (string[i] != '\0')
            if ((s = check(string[i++], s)) < 0)
                break;
        for (i = 0 ; i < nfinals ; i++)
            if (f[i] == s )
                final = 1;
        if (final == 1)
            printf("\n String is accepted");
        else
            printf("String is rejected");

        printf("\nDo you want to continue.?  \n(y/n) ");
    }
    while (getch() == 'y');

    return getch();
}
```

Comment: _doesn't work_ Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getch() == 'n') {
    // print something
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

should fflush your buffer before taking char as an input

```
do
{//..your code
printf("\nDo you want to continue.?  \n(y/n) ");
scanf("%c",&ch);
scanf("%c",&ch);
}
while (ch == 'y');
```

Comment: Using `fflush` on `stdin` is Undefined Behaviour

Comment: replace fflush(stdin); with scanf("%c",&ch); i.e put scanf("%c",&ch); 2 times